# Python polynomial roots are inaccurate

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, polynomials

An algorithm that I'm trying to implement requires finding the roots of a 10th degree polynomial, which I created with sympy, it looks like this:

```py
import sympy
import numpy as np
det = sympy.Poly(1.3339507303385e-16*z**10 + 6.75390067076469e-14*z**9 + 7.18791227134351e-12*z**8 + 2.27504286959352e-10*z**7 + 2.37058998324426e-8*z**6 + 1.63916629439745e-6*z**5 + 3.0608041245671e-5*z**4 + 4.83564348562906e-8*z**3 + 2.0248073519853e-5*z**2 - 4.73126177166988e-7*z + 1.1495883206077e-6)
```

For finding the roots of the polynomial, I use the following code:

```py
coefflist = det.coeffs()
solutions = np.roots(coefflist)
print(coefflist)
[1.33395073033850e-16, 6.75390067076469e-14, 7.18791227134351e-12, 2.27504286959352e-10, 2.37058998324426e-8, 1.63916629439745e-6, 3.06080412456710e-5, 4.83564348562906e-8, 2.02480735198530e-5, -4.73126177166988e-7, 1.14958832060770e-6]

print(solutions)
[-3.70378229e+02+0.00000000e+00j -1.18366138e+02+0.00000000e+00j
  2.71097137e+01+5.77011644e+01j  2.71097137e+01-5.77011644e+01j
 -3.59084863e+01+1.44819591e-02j -3.59084863e+01-1.44819591e-02j
  2.60969082e-03+7.73805425e-01j  2.60969082e-03-7.73805425e-01j
  1.42936329e-02+2.49877948e-01j  1.42936329e-02-2.49877948e-01j]
```

However, when I substitute `z` with a root, lets say the first one, the result is not zero, but some number:

```py
print(det.subs(z,solutions[0]))
-1.80384169514123e-6
```

I would have expected, that the result probably isn't the integer `0`, but `1e-6` is pretty bad (it should be zero, right?). Is there a mistake in my code? Is this inaccuracy normal? Any thoughts/suggestions would be helpful. Is there a more accurate alternative to compute the roots of a 10th degree polynomial?

Comment: Why do you say that `1e-6` is "pretty bad"? `1e-6 == 0.000001`, so it is not too far from it. These errors most likely come from numerical approximations of your floats. Mind that you have very small polynomial coefficients already.

Comment: Your expectations of computer mathematics is too high, I'm afraid. Internally the computer only uses 64 bits to represent a real value. And of that, only 52 bits are used for the significance. With each operation, some precision disappears. Finding roots for a 10th order polynomial is quite a complex algorithm, so be happy with what you get.

Comment: Finding roots of polynomials is numerically ill conditioned and your coefficients range over 10 orders of magnitude. You'll need to use higher precision arithmetic to do better than that: you can do that with sympy but not if you are using numpy's roots function.

Comment: Thank you guys a lot for answering so quickly. I suspected that the problem is the small coefficients. I was under the impression, that the result is bad, because the largest coefficient in the polynomial is about the same size as the error that I get, which doesn't help with my confidence in the roots, which were found. I'll try sympy, as suggested. If that doesn't help, it's ok too :)

Comment: See [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need sympy, the methods in numpy are completely sufficient. Define the polynomial by its list of coefficients and compute the roots

```py
p=[1.33395073033850e-16, 6.75390067076469e-14, 7.18791227134351e-12, 2.27504286959352e-10, 2.37058998324426e-8, 1.63916629439745e-6, 3.06080412456710e-5, 4.83564348562906e-8, 2.02480735198530e-5, -4.73126177166988e-7, 1.14958832060770e-6]
sol= np.roots(p); sol
```

giving the result

```
array([ -3.70378229e+02 +0.00000000e+00j,  -1.18366138e+02 +0.00000000e+00j,
         2.71097137e+01 +5.77011644e+01j,   2.71097137e+01 -5.77011644e+01j,
        -3.59084863e+01 +1.44819592e-02j,  -3.59084863e+01 -1.44819592e-02j,
         2.60969082e-03 +7.73805425e-01j,   2.60969082e-03 -7.73805425e-01j,
         1.42936329e-02 +2.49877948e-01j,   1.42936329e-02 -2.49877948e-01j])
```

and evaluate the polynomials at these approximate roots

```
np.polyval(p,sol)
```

giving the array

```
array([  2.28604877e-06 +0.00000000e+00j,   1.30435230e-10 +0.00000000e+00j,
         1.05461854e-11 -7.56043461e-12j,   1.05461854e-11 +7.56043461e-12j,
        -3.98439686e-14 +6.84489332e-17j,  -3.98439686e-14 -6.84489332e-17j,
         1.18584613e-20 +1.59976730e-21j,   1.18584613e-20 -1.59976730e-21j,
         6.35274710e-22 +1.74700545e-21j,   6.35274710e-22 -1.74700545e-21j])
```

Obviously, evaluating a polynomial close to a root involves lots of catastrophic cancellations, that is, the intermediate terms are large of opposite sign and cancel out, but their errors are proportional to their original sizes. To get an estimate of the combined error size, replace the polynomial coefficients with their absolute values and also the evaluation points.

```
np.polyval(np.abs(p),np.abs(sol))
```

resulting in

```
array([  1.81750423e+10,   8.40363409e+05,   
         8.08166359e+03,   8.08166359e+03,
         2.44160616e+02,   2.44160616e+02,
         2.50963696e-05,   2.50963696e-05,
         2.65889696e-06,   2.65889696e-06])
```

In the case of the first root, the scale multiplied with the machine constant gives an error scale of `1e+10*1e-16=1e-6`, which means that the value at the root is as good as zero within the framework of double-precision floating point.